# Angular 4 Production Settings in Different Build

Tags: angular, typescript

This seems like a very simple thing. I want to generate a build of an Angular 4 app for a test environment with prod optimization.

I have created a named environment file (environment.testserver.ts) and I am able to run "ng build --environment=testserver" to generate the content. However the content is not fully optimized and minified the way it is when you use "-prod". However, when I add that switch, it then uses "environment.prod.ts" instead of "environment.testserver.ts".

How do I direct the CLI to use prod optimizations in a different environment?

Comment: What does your environment.testserver.ts file look like? The main optimization you need to be prod-like is --aot=true

Comment: It contains the same settings as "environment.ts" but with values that reflect the test environment. Specfically, it contains the following:
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  BaseApiHref: "http://testserver/api"
};

Comment: The problem is even more fundamental: When I run this command: "ng-build --environment=testserver", the compiled application contains the environment settings from prod instead of testserver. I can't make any sense of this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you updated your .angular-cli.json "environments" property to add your new test environment? Once you add it there, you can just call --testenvironment in your build script

Comment: I have updated the ".angular-cli.json" file. I also tried using the "--testenvironment" shorthand and I still end up with prod settings instead.